# php artisan make controller command try connecting to mysql and throwing connection error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

when i run any php artisan commands make,key its throwing an error saying

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it.      (SQL: select * from `system`
> where `key` = woocommerce_version limit 1)
>
> In Connector.php line 70:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it.

why it tries to connect to mysql database it has nothing to do with it

my server is iis i don't know if its mis-configured, but the same laravel application in localhost shows no error

Comment: check if you have queries in service provider

Comment: Maybe you forgot to start up mysql service. It is ussual stack.